# How to specify instance name as part of aws_instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How to specify instance name as part of aws_instance, the instance being launched doesn't have a display name associated with it and is shown as empty in the EC2 console. Note: instance_id is properly shown

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance

Answer (score 5):

Instance name is just a **tag** with key `Name`:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t3.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "MyInstanceName"
  }
}
```